# Copy iPhone file from macOS Finder using AppleScript or JAX

Tags: automation, applescript, finder

My setup

- macOS 10.15.7

The recent macOS can access iOS app documents on a physically connected device directly from Finder. But this process seems to need human intervention.

I wonder if I could retrieve my iOS app's file from Finder programmatically using AppleScript or JAX. So far I haven't found a way

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself.

The solution is not exactly as my title but it does the job: I can now access app documents from macOS programmatically without modifying my app code.

### Short answer

I can use [ifuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) as part of `libimobiledevice`.

### Details

Here are the steps taken.

1. Install [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io) , which

> allows you to extend macOS's native file handling capabilities via
> third-party file systems.

mine is `4.0.5`.

2. Install ifuse and `ideviceinstaller` from Homebrew.

```sh
brew install ifuse
```

mine is `1.1.4`.

```sh
brew install ideviceinstaller
```

mine is `1.1.1`.

3. Find your app's App ID using `ideviceinstaller`.

```sh
ideviceinstaller -l | grep "my_keyword"
```

This gives your app's ID and name. Assume tat the id was `com.my.app`

4. Mount the Documents folder, e.g., onto my desktop.

```sh
mkdir -p "~/Desktop/myappdoc"

ifuse --documents com.my.app "~/Desktop/myappdoc"
```

Now my app folder is mounted at the specified location.

To unmount so that next time around my script can still mount the drive at the same location,

```sh
umount "~/Desktop/myappfoc"
```

Comment: Hello @kakyo thanks for sharing your solution. Please advise how did you manage to get ifuse installed without the required dependency osxfuse? I have been following your steps in order to mount the root of a jailbroken iphone but mine installation of the ifuse is failing due to the following error: "ifuse: FUSE for macOS is required for this software. OsxfuseRequirement unsatisfied!  Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.". I have installed the macFUSE though.

Comment: forgot to mention that I have MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 and trying to mount an iphone 7 plus (SoC Apple A10) iOS 11.1.1

Comment: @kels Sorry, I haven't tested this with jailbroken phones, so I can't comment on your findings unfortunately. If you have a jailbroken phones, have you tried to run ssh/sftp from your macOS to transfer files to the phone or run remote programs on the phone? I think in theory you can.